# Use output of NDSolve as an integration limit of NIntegrate

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation

I've been working on a ODE, for a function `y[t]`, that, due to it's complexity, has to be solved numerically. I then need to use the results of NDSolve, which I store in the variable $s$, in the following manner:

```
Plot[
     NIntegrate[
                f[r],{r,b,Evaluate[Sqrt[{(y[t])^2+b^2}/.s]]}
               ],
     {t,0,5}
    ]
```

which returns the following errors:

```
NIntegrate::nlim: r = {20.025} is not a valid limit of integration. >>
NIntegrate::nlim: r = {20.025} is not a valid limit of integration. >>
NIntegrate::nlim: r = {19.6024} is not a valid limit of integration. >>
General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::nlim will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

It seems that the problem is due to $\text{Evaluate}$ returning the number in parentheses...I've tried the function $\text{N}$ but it has the same problem. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong. Can anyone help me?

**Edit:** I shall post the complete code as suggested in the comments:

```
Module[{b = 1., k = 1., Vt0 = 2., L0 = 20.},
 s = NDSolve[
   {y''[t] - (y'[t])^2 (b^2/((b^2 + (y[t])^2) y[t]) - y[t]/(
         b^2 (Exp[(y[t])^2/b^2] - 1))) - (z'[t])^2 (-1/(
         y[t] Exp[(y[t])^2/b^2]) (Exp[(y[t])^2/b^2] - 
           1) (b^2 + (y[t])^2)) + k*(b^2 y[t])/(b^2 + (y[t])^2) == 0, 
    y[0] == L0, y'[0] == 0,
    z''[t] + 2*y'[t]*z'[t]*(y[t]/(b^2 + (y[t])^2)) == 0, z'[0] == Vt0,
     z[0] == 0},
   {z, y}, {t, 0, 5}
   ];
 f[r_] := Sqrt[E^(r^2/b^2)/(-E + E^(r^2/b^2)) - 1];

 Plot[
  NIntegrate[f[r], {r, b, Evaluate[Sqrt[(y[t])^2 + b^2] /. s]}],
  {t, 0, 5}
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: you shall put info on `f[],s,r`..!!

Comment: @Nasser ups. Yes \sqrt is Sqrt[]. I copied as Latex before used the 'code' command and left that artifact.

Comment: @Blackbird Just edited to include the complete code. The function $\text{z[t]}$ shall not matter for the error.

Comment: `M` is saying that you are specifying an interpolating function where it needs a constant.You need to look into this.probably your approach is wrong.Upper limit of `NIntegrate` cannot be a function returning function.

Comment: @Blackbird Based on your suggestion I figured out what was wrong with my approach. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know if this plot makes sense of not. But you have complex values showing up from your `NIntegrate`. Any way, may be you can look at this and see if it look ok.

Let us spread things out a little. Once it is working ok, then you can make a Module and collapse back into one nice long expression.

```
b = 1.;
k = 1.;
Vt0 = 2.;
L0 = 20.;

sol = NDSolve[{y''[
       t] - (y'[t])^2 (b^2/((b^2 + (y[t])^2) y[t]) - 
         y[t]/(b^2 (Exp[(y[t])^2/b^2] - 1))) - (z'[
          t])^2 (-1/(y[t] Exp[(y[t])^2/b^2]) (Exp[(y[t])^2/b^2] - 
           1) (b^2 + (y[t])^2)) + k*(b^2 y[t])/(b^2 + (y[t])^2) == 0, 
    y[0] == L0, y'[0] == 0, 
    z''[t] + 2*y'[t]*z'[t]*(y[t]/(b^2 + (y[t])^2)) == 0, z'[0] == Vt0,
     z[0] == 0}, {z, y}, {t, 0, 5}];
ysol = y /. First@sol;
```

make sure solution looks ok before the next step

```
Plot[ysol[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[r_?NumericQ] := Sqrt[E^(r^2/b^2)/(-E + E^(r^2/b^2)) - 1];
```

check

```
f[r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

make the data. I used `Abs` since you have complex numbers otherwise.

```
data = Table[{t,Abs @ NIntegrate[f[r], {r, b, Sqrt[ysol[t]^2 + b^2]}]}, {t, 0,5, .05}];
```

check some points:

```
data[[1 ;; 3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

plot

```
ListLinePlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "NIntegrate"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way to do the above, is to first calculate the upper limit in a vector, make sure it is ok, then use that next for the integration. Same result is found.

```
upperLimit = Table[Sqrt[ysol[t]^2 + b^2], {t, 0, 5, .01}];
ListLinePlot[upperLimit, Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = Table[{i, Abs @ NIntegrate[f[r], {r, b, upperLimit[[i]]}]}, {i,
     Length[upperLimit]}];

ListLinePlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"i", "NIntegrate"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not see anything interesting here. Making t steps smaller, one get straight line.

Comment: I believe that your approach is correct.
I've figured out what was wrong with mine. I just had to equal the upper limit expression to a variable, say $\text{x}$. And then in NIntegrate use $\text{x[[1]]}$ for the upper limit. But certainly your approach is very interesting and I foresee that I'll check it out oftentimes. Thank You very much